# Tensorflow: Initializing dependent variables

Tags: variables, tensorflow, initialization

I am trying to initialize some variables based on value of other variables. Here is a minimal script:

```
a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
b = a + 2
c = tf.Variable(b, name='c')
d = c + 3
e = tf.Variable(d, name='e')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([a, c, e]))
```

This throws the following exception:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use 
uninitialized value a.
```

But if I remove variable e it works fine:

```
a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
b = a + 2
c = tf.Variable(b, name='c')
d = c + 3
#e = tf.Variable(d, name='e')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([a, c]))  # [1, 3]
```

I tried to overcome the problem by using of the `tf.control_dependencies([b, d])` before declaring e but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is just to execute the code as it is then this does it.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.Variable(1, name='a')
    a.initializer.run()
    b = a + 2
    c = tf.Variable(b, name='c')
    d = c + 3
    e = tf.Variable(d, name='e')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([a, c, e]))
```

Further research about this is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15077)